# select count(*) on a big table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a big table (approx. 150 M rows), and if I try to run a simple select count(*) on it, then mysql works for about an hour and then throws an error.

I'm assuming this is not due to a limitation of mysql, rather a problem on my side, but I have no idea where to start looking. any ideas?

the table is innodb
mysql 5.5 on linux

Comment: That's a big table, although an hour sounds pretty excessive... have you tried doing a count on a specific column?  What database engine are you using?

Comment: I'm no MySQL expert, it immediately occurs to me that you might want try `SELECT COUNT([a single column, preferrably something simple/small])` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: what error you get ? can you share this error ?

Comment: it's a table with two columns (a many-many connection table), the engine is innodb.
One thing I haven't mentioned is the table is heavily written into.

Comment: what the error you are getting ?

Comment: after an hour, I get:
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Answer (score 2):

you can check it with table status like this

```
  SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name LIKE 'table_name';
```

you see the rows column....

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, but still excellent!
thanks!

Comment: @strum No, it's not. The number shown there doesn't need to be correct. These are just approximate values. The bigger the table the farer away it might get from true value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count(1) instead of count(*)`

Try ::

```
Select count(1) from my_table
```

Comment: I assumed it won't make a difference, since the table has only two rows (integers). and indeed it didn't :-(
But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to speed up queries like this is with a [covering index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Covering_Index). This will allow you to scan through the rows you want, but require fewer bytes of I/O per row (since you're only scanning a portion of each row's data, not the entire row). Furthermore, if your index is sorted in the same way that your query is, you can avoid the cost of a sort and can scan vastly fewer rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Information Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html).

> SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema =
>   YOUR_DB_NAME AND table_name = YOUR_TABLE_NAME